# Multiple AKDevice inputs with AudioKit

Tags: audiokit

I'm new to AudioKit (but a reasonable amount of previous experience with CoreAudio).

Is there any way to attach multiple specific device inputs to a single mixer?  I'm wanting to record a couple of mics, plus another virtual device. So far I see only a single "AKMicrophone" which appears to represent the current default input device.  If I do a .setDevice on it; that call also changes the current default input device in system prefs (which I definitely dont want).

I feel like I'm missing a core concept.  Any tips appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with AudioKit as its currently set up. It was highly iOS driven early on and we don't have good support for multiple inputs or outputs for that matter. We're looking to improve upon this as we do have a high profile client who also wants to do more pro level stuff on macOS with AudioKit. We'd welcome any changes you'd want to pull request in.

Comment: Given it's current state (and I havn't looked at code yet), do you think that'd be hard? I've written my own "engine" on top of the existing apple supplied CA classes, using deprecated AUGraph. I'd rather not do that again, hence looking for exsiting solution. It might make more sense for me to put that effort into bringing multiple inputs to an existing framework, if it's (architecturally) well positioned for it.  Also; I've little experience with AVAudioEngine, and am unsure yet if multiple inputs are doable using it.

Comment: It is definitely doable and we actually are working on it, not necessarily because of your question, just really good timing.

Comment: Good news then :). Ive been held up working on this (other website stuff). Currently playing with AVAudioEngine to see if I can get it to accept multiple inputs in a graph. At this point, to me, that isn't clear. One. Fine. But ... say, 4? Not so fine :)

Comment: If there's a branch I can review/help with, I'd be happy to both expand my experience with CA/AV, and help.

Comment: It will be on the v5-develop branch on AudioKit

Comment: @AureliusProchazka did your development of multiple ins and outs land in a public branch anywhere yet? I’ve been deep diving in the code to see if it’s possible and/or where I could help, but haven’t found it yet.